# Why does Kafka Akka Actor give Java Heap Space Error?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, akka

I am running a Kafka application with Akka. The application is hosted in OpenShift and the applications quite sporadically throws Java Heap Space errors:

> Uncaught error from thread [transparency_16_1_a_ecp_aggregator-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]: Java heap space, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[transparency_16_1_a_ecp_aggregator]

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source) at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1306) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1242) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1215) at KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.getGeneratingUnits(KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.java:84) at .GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.consumeGeneratingUnits(GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.java:65) at actor.GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor$$Lambda$633/0x00000001005d2440.apply(Unknown Source) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:214) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:213) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:269) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:270) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)

Which leads to

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source) at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:306) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.maybeLeaveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:1114) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.close(AbstractCoordinator.java:1074) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.close(ConsumerCoordinator.java:980) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2411) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2378) at KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.getGeneratingUnits(KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.java:92) at actor.GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.consumeGeneratingUnits(GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.java:65) at
> actor.GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor$$Lambda$633/0x00000001005d2440.apply(Unknown Source) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:214) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:213) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:269) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:270) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)

and

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to close kafka consumer at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2430) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2378) at repository.KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.getGeneratingUnits(KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.java:92) at actor.GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.consumeGeneratingUnits(GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.java:65) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:214) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:213) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:269) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:270) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231) at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source) at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:113) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576) at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481) at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:306) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.maybeLeaveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:1114) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.close(AbstractCoordinator.java:1074) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.close(ConsumerCoordinator.java:980) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2411) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2378) at repository.KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.getGeneratingUnits(KafkaGeneratingUnitsRepository.java:92) at actor.GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.consumeGeneratingUnits(GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor.java:65) at
> actor.GeneratingUnitsConsumerActor$$Lambda$633/0x00000001005d2440.apply(Unknown Source) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:214) at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:213) at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:269) at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:270) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)

Looking at the pod's memory usage
[image: memory usage]
it does not look like a Heap Space error should be thrown? What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: That graph is the eden space of the heap (where small newly-allocated objects live).  The usage of eden space (which is typically small) tells you nothing about overall heap space.

Comment: In short, you almost certainly are running out of heap space.